# Dajax/dajaxice problems: "Dajax is not defined" and "missing } after statement"

Tags: django

I wanted to play with dajax for my actual django project. I stardet looking at the [simple form example](http://www.dajaxproject.com/forms/) on the website, but i cannot get it to work correctly.
I keep on getting this error (with firebug) "Error: Dajax is not defined"

Also i was trying to implement the [dajaxice example](http://www.dajaxproject.com/dajaxice/), but i get this other error:

```
Error: missing } after function body
Source File: http://localhost:8000/dajaxice/dajaxice.core.js
Line: 30, Column: 52
Source Code:
    alert("data.message")({"message": "Buuuuuuuuu!"})
```

Here are my files (ajax.py and javascript.js) and my view function. The html template is analog to the one in the website.

ajax.py

```
from django.utils import simplejson
from dajaxice.core import dajaxice_functions, Dajaxice
from dajax.core import Dajax

def myexample(request):
    return simplejson.dumps({'message':'Buuuuuuuuu!'})

dajaxice_functions.register(myexample)


def updatecombo(request, option):
    dajax = Dajax()
    options = [ ['Madrid','Barcelona','Vitoria','Burgos'],
                ['Paris','Lille','Nantes','Lyon'],
                ['London','Manchester','Liverpool','Someother'],]
    out = ""
    for o in options[int(option)]:
         out += "%s<option value='#'>%s" % (out,o,)
    dajax.assign('#combo2', 'innerHTML', out)
return dajax.json()

dajaxice_functions.register(updatecombo)
```

javascript.js

```
function the_callback(data){
        alert(data.message);
}
```

my view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def basic_view(request):
        return render_to_response('test.html', {}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

urls.py

```
import os
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from dajaxice.core import dajaxice_autodiscover
from dajax_test.tester.views import *


from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

dajaxice_autodiscover()

site_media = os.path.join(
        os.path.dirname(__file__), 'site_media'
)

urlpatterns = patterns('',

        (r'^%s/' % settings.DAJAXICE_MEDIA_PREFIX, include('dajaxice.urls')),
        (r'^site_media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': site_media},),


        (r'^dajaxice/$', basic_view)
)
```

i have settings.py configured like they say on the main website.
i don't know what's wrong, google doesn't seem to help (any search for dajax/dajaxice gives results for ajax... pretty obvious, pretty annoying...) any hint/help?

Comment: UPDATE: by updating dajaxice via easy_install i managed to get the button working (myexample function is now working). Still i have the error on the updatecombo function ("Dajax is not defined")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i'm answering my own question since i figured it out. it was a stupid problem&mistake...

i just forgot to include

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}jquery.dajax.core.js"></script>
```

into my html template. hope this is helpful for somebody, oneday!
if you're not using jquery, try [one of the others](https://github.com/jorgebastida/django-dajax/tree/master/src)